# GAE Python Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine

I have a python application that I am migrating from Python2.7 to Python 3.7. Since GAE is deprecating the appengine python module, I wanted to understand how the community is migrating the Unit Tests written using `testbed` module from appengine SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that `testbed` as well as whole `google.appengine.ext` has been removed with no further information regarding migration according to [reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.testbed):

> These APIs are no longer recommended. Apps that use these APIs can only run in the App Engine Python 2 runtime and will need to migrate to other APIs and services before migrating to the App Engine Python 3 runtime.

In [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#testing) describing differences between Python 2 and 3 you can find that:

> Any standard Python testing framework can be used to write your unit, integration, and system tests

I am afraid that only way is to use different API. There is [document about migration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/testing#test_locally), but it only contain testing locally.

It seems there is no easy way to do it :(.

I hope it will help!

Comment: I was able to build out a separate utility which helps retain the old testbed structure to a great extent and reduce the migration effort. I ll try to share that soon.